# (Theorem) If $G$ is a simple group of odd order , then $G \cong \mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying Dumit Foote. I have seen this result in this book. Please help me solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: I too remember seeing this in Dummit and Foote.  When the result was introduced, I remember it saying that the proof was *very* nontrivial and took hundreds of pages of heavy machinery...

Comment: This follows quickly from the Feit-Thompson theorem.

Comment: @ T . Bongers : I have tried , but google shows different results .

Comment: This **is** the Feit-Thomson theorem. (I say this in the way I would say $\psi(x)\sim x$ is the PNT, I don't mean it's literally stated the same way).

Comment: may be this is not a better place for **very nontrivial and took hundreds of pages of heavy machinery..** ... you could try in matheoverflow i guess...

Comment: Feit-Thompson gives that $G$ is solvable, we hence have $G' \lhd G$. As $G$ is simple, $G' = 1$, hence $G$ is abelian. But an abelian simple group is of prime order.

Comment: @thomasandrews No, that is not true. In fact, the mentioned result is an important part of the classification.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For dates, Feit-Thompson was 1963 while the classification wasn't really finished until the late 70s into early 80s. (Omitting the quasi-thin fix.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I was misremembering another result. Commented deleted. It's still a very hard-to-prove result...

Comment: @thomas Indeed - I looked up Robinson's book to find the date, and he describes it as "exceedingly difficult". I also remember someone telling me that, at the time, it was the longest published proof. This was probably not quite true, but the page numbers imply 254 pages. Which is not short...

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that the theorem in the title is equivalent to the Feit-Thompson theorem, which states that every finite group of odd order is solvable. Proving the theorem is very difficult, the original proof was about 200 pages long.

Comment: Actually the proof of the FT-theorem consists in assuming that there exists a finite nonabelian simple group of odd order and developing its theory so as to eventually reach a contradiction. So the statement that every finite simple group of odd order is even closer to the original theorem than the corollary that every group of odd order is solvable.